# Keycloak intergration with IDAP as a PingID

Tags: keycloak

I am totally new to keycloak and trying to integrate keycloak with PingID as a IDAP.

While signing in, I get a success saml response but Keycloak is throwing error message:

e[0me[33m05:26:18,036 WARN [org.keycloak.events] (default task-18) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_RESPONSE_ERROR, realmId=UIB, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=X.X.X.X, error=invalid_logout_response, reason=missing_required_destination

“e[0me[33m05:26:18,036 WARN [org.keycloak.events] (default task-18) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_RESPONSE_ERROR, realmId=UIB, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=X.X.X.X, error=invalid_logout_response, reason=missing_required_destination”

I have tried searching for the resolution but unable to find any.

Any help on How to integrate with PingID (saml as a IDAP) for keycloak would be appreciated.

I tried looking over internet and nothing is helpful. Please help me resolve the issue.